# What is the use of STATIC_URL

Tags: django

Regarding static files. i was able to understand the following:

- STATIC_ROOT - files where the static files would be copied op collectstatic command
- STATIC_DIR- list where static files live.

Now what is the use of `STATIC_URL`, Read through a lot of resources, not able to understand it.

Can any one please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_DIR is where *additional* static files live, STATIC_URL is where static files live.

Basically STATIC_URL is necessary, where STATIC_DIR is not but can help clarify addition (such as template static files) locations.

Comment: but my static fils live in the dirctory provided by static_dir./

Comment: also, whatever value i put in static_url- images and files load,only thing is the relative url for accessing the files change(which is visible in eclipse console)

Comment: i know something is wrong with my understanding,but not able to figure out

Comment: @parameswar I believe that Daniel Roseman means that this answer is totally wrong. Essentially I agree that this answer is wrong.

Comment: I'm glad I checked this since I clearly don't understand it as well as I thought.  I've only ever run this on my local server, and this is what I come to understand.  Daniel's answer seems more correct as well as accounts for production.

Answer (score 0):

The settings mean quite different things.

As you've said, STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT (there's no Django setting called "STATIC_DIR") refer to locations on disk. STATIC_URL - as the name implies - refers to the URL that these files should be served under.

In development, Django will automatically serve files from STATIC_ROOT at STATIC_URL. In production, it's up to you to configure your server to do so.

Comment: yes, i meant STATICFILES_DIRS . did not get this part-"STATIC_URL - as the name implies - refers to the URL that these files should be served under." - i am using the inbuilt python server (manage.py runserver)- only thing i noted is, i can  accss the css .images and all using http://localhost:8001/<static_urlpath>

Comment: if i deploy the project to ,say nginx, do i need to do something different ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; I said both of those things in my answer. Yes, the images are accessed via the path specified in STATIC_URL; and yes, you need to configure nginx separately.

Comment: ok,let me put it this way: 1. my static files are under djangoproj/app1/tmplats/static - i have mentiond the relative path in staticfils_dir and when i give collectstatic,it copies the files and puts under the folder corresponding to static_root. whreas my static_url is completely different- as of now i have put it as static_url='dummy'. whn i start the server, the files can be accessed using localhost:port/dummy/css/sample.css - so,my question is what exactly is the use of static_url, as i see it automatically configures the access path for the files,but thats just it.

Comment: Yes. That is what it does.

Comment: ok, thanks, i think it is of no use, i may be naive, but django dev can provide the same functionality for static_root,why introduce a different path ?

Comment: I really, really, don't understand what you are saying. A file path is different from a URL.

Comment: Sorry, Firstly huge thanks for taking time to answer the questions. What i meant was , as a developer, i care for two things:1. static_root- where i need the static files to be copied 2. staticfils_dir - where the static files reside. If i fire up the python runserver, i get what i want . Do i really need to care about  static_url  ?( i understand it needs to be there ,else django gives an error, but thats the way it was designed ).

Comment: @parameswar Maybe you'll find http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/21/how-django-static-files-work-in-production/ useful.